# SELECT subCategory which equals parentCategory = value from outer table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a products table and I need to put discount on some products from a given sub category, which has parent category in another table.

```
TABLE products:

category_id      sku      discount     
-----------------------------------
8             3141          NULL 
7             4333          NULL 
7             601           NULL
3             405           NULL  


TABLE product_category:

id      parent_id           slug     
-----------------------------------
8             18          somename 
7             3           somename
```

It's a pretty simple question but I can't figure out how to use the parent_id column to update my products table simply, instead of writing down every subcategory id like this:

```
UPDATE products 
SET discount = 25 
WHERE category_id IN (1,4,5,6 etc..);
```

I want to update the products table by selecting the subcategory's parent id from the **product_category** table.

Comment: Such hierarchical relationships require some sort of recursive CTE (or similar) support or a more detailed data model.  Recursive CTEs are available in MySQL 8+, but not in earlier versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE products 
SET discount = 15
WHERE category_id IN (SELECT id FROM product_category WHERE parent_id = 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this-

```
UPDATE products 
SET discount = 25 
WHERE category_id IN (SELECT Parent_id FROM Product_Category);
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider an `UPDATE` + `JOIN`:

```
UPDATE products p 
INNER JOIN product_category c ON p.category_id = c.id
SET p.discount = 25 ;
```